# Showing that $P (|X_1| < \Gamma , |X_2| < \Gamma)$ is increasing in $|\rho|$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, correlation

Assume $(X_1,X_2 )^T$ is mean $0$ bivariate normal distributed with covariance matrix $\Sigma = \left (\begin{matrix} 1 & \rho \\ \rho & 1 \end{matrix} \right)$ and let $\Gamma > 0$ a positive constant. Then i would like to show that
$P (|X_1| < \Gamma , |X_2| < \Gamma)$ is increasing in $|\rho|$.

Any tips? I already tried to simply use the integral representation of the probability, but could not show it.

Comment: Are we meant to assume that $X_1,X_2$ are independent variables?

Comment: no they are bivariate normal distributed.

Comment: The bivariate normality is implied in the question.

Comment: @J.Field Sorry I missed that, thanks for clarifying

Comment: @StubbornAtom saying that a vector is normally distributed can either mean that its entries are iid normally distributed or that the whole vector has a multivariate normal distribution

Comment: @Omnomnomnom It always means the second one. Independent or not should be clear from the covariance matrix.

Comment: Applying the substitution 
$$
\pmatrix{y_1\\y_2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \rho^2}}\pmatrix{1&-\rho\\0 & 1-\rho^2}
$$
Leads to an integral of the form
$$
\frac{A} {\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\iint_{R} \exp\left(y_1^2 + y_2^2\right)\,dy_1\,dy_2,
$$
but the resulting region of integration depends on $\rho$ and might be tricky to deal with

Comment: Another approach worth considering: it would suffice to show that
$$
\frac{d P}{d \rho} = \frac{d}{d\rho} \iint_R f(x_1,x_2) dx_1 dx_2= 
\ \iint_R \frac{\partial f}{\partial \rho}\,(x_1,x_2) dx_1 dx_2 < 0
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the pdf $f(x_1,x_2)$ satisfies $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \rho} > 0$.  From there, it suffices to observe that
$$
\frac{d P}{d \rho} = \frac{d}{d\rho} \iint_R f(x_1,x_2) dx_1 dx_2= 
\ \iint_R \frac{\partial f}{\partial \rho}\,(x_1,x_2) \,dx_1 dx_2 < 0,
$$
where $R$ denotes the rectangle $[-\Gamma,\Gamma]\times [-\Gamma,\Gamma]$.  After computing $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \rho}$, you should find that one of the resulting integrals can be solved as an iterated integral; solve the inner-integral with the substitution $u_2 = x_2^2$.

Comment: Is it a well known fact, that the derivate suffices the inequality? I checked it myself, but it was kind of lenghty.

Comment: Yes: it is well known that to show that a function $I(\rho)$ is increasing, it suffices to show that $dI/d\rho$ is positive

Comment: @J.Field Honestly, I prefer the other answer

Comment: No i meant if it is well known, that the inequality $\frac{\partial f}{\partial p} > 0$ holds,but i guess i´ll take the other solution.

Answer (score 3):

This follows from [Mehler's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehler_kernel#Probability_version), in the form 
$$f(x_1,x_2)=\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac {\rho^n}{n!} He_n(x_1)He_n(x_2),$$ 
where $f$ is the joint density of $(X_1,X_2)$,  $\phi$ is the marginal density of the $X_i$, and $He_n(x)$ is a ["probabilist's" Hermite polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials).  Integrating over $[-\Gamma,\Gamma]\times[-\Gamma,\Gamma]$ yields an expression of form $$
I(\Gamma,\rho) := P(|X_1|<\Gamma, |X_2|<\Gamma) = 
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac {\rho^n}{n!}\left(\int_{-\Gamma}^\Gamma \phi(x)He_n(x)\,dx\right)^2,\tag 1$$
all of whose terms are non-negative.  In fact $He_n$ is an odd polynomial if $n$ is odd, so the odd terms in (1) vanish, so we see $I(\Gamma,\rho)$ is given by a power series in $\rho^2$ with non-negative coefficients.

Comment: Nice trick. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_{\rho}$ be the density of $(X_1,X_2)$.

An interesting identity I stumbled upon in this connection is

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\rho}f_{\rho}(x,y)=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}f_{\rho}(x,y)$$

This is part of a general result due to [Plackett (1954)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2332716?seq=1).

Then differentiating under the integral sign,

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{d\rho}P(|X_1|<c,|X_2|<c)&=\int_{-c}^c\int_{-c}^c \frac{\partial}{\partial\rho}f_{\rho}(x,y)\,dx\,dy
\\&=\int_{-c}^c\int_{-c}^c \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}f_{\rho}(x,y)\,dx\,dy
\\&=\int_{-c}^c \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\int_{-c}^c \frac{\partial}{\partial y} f_{\rho}(x,y)\,dy\right)dx
\\&=\int_{-c}^c \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f_{\rho}(x,c)\,dx-\int_{-c}^c \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f_{\rho}(x,-c)\,dx
\\&=f_{\rho}(c,c)-f_{\rho}(-c,c)-f_{\rho}(c,-c)+f_{\rho}(-c,-c)
\\&=2\left(f_{\rho}(c,c)-f_{\rho}(c,-c)\right)
\end{align}

That is, for some $c>0$ we have

$$\frac{d}{d\rho}P(|X_1|<c,|X_2|<c)=\frac1{\pi\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\left[e^{-c^2/(1+\rho)}-e^{-c^2/(1-\rho)}\right]$$

Note that $\rho > 0\implies -\frac1{1+\rho}>-\frac1{1-\rho}$, so that right hand side of the above equation is positive for $\rho\in (0,1)$. Similarly it is negative for $\rho\in (-1,0)$. Hence the probability is increasing in $|\rho|$.